# Linux: how to insert missing text between delimiters in a file

Tags: bash

Let's say we have a text file that has one or more pairs of delimiters which surround various directives. Each delimiter appears on a line by itself, as follows:

```
{
   directive1
   ...
}
{ 
  directive1
  ...
}
...
```

note that the opening delimiter is different than the closing one. Using "standard" Linux tools (sed, awk, grep, perl, etc), how can I go through this file and check each pair of delimiters (block) for a specific directive (say "DirectiveX"): if it doesn't exist then insert it into that block. If it already exists, don't change that particular block.

Comment: Where in a block should the directive be inserted?

Comment: Let's say right before the closing delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use Perl for such a task. The following script works for the most trivial cases (no nesting, directive never on the same line as the curly brackets):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($inside, $found);
while (<>) {
    if (/\{/) {
        $inside = 1;
        $found  = 0;
    } elsif (/\}/) {
        print "directive\n" unless $found;
        $inside = $found = 0;
    } elsif (/directive/ and $inside) {
        $found = 1;
    }
    print;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `directiveX` does not appear in a block, this prints `MyDirjective` at the end of the block:

```
awk -v RS='\n}\n' '{print $0} /{/ {if (!/directiveX/) print "  MyDirective"; print "}"}' file
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS='\n}\n'`

  awk divides the file up into "records." This statement tells awk that a closing brace on its own line is to separate two records.
- `print $0`

  This prints out the existing record as is.
- `/{/`

  This tests whether the new block includes an open brace.  If it doesn't the commands which follow are skipped.
- `if (!/directiveX/) print "MyDirective"`

  If the existing record does not contain `directiveX`, then print `MyDirective`.  (`/directiveX/` tests for the presence of `directiveX` and the exclamation point `!` negates that test.)
- `print RS`

  Finally, at the end of each record, print the closing brace (the Record Separator).

#### Example

Consider this sample file:

```
$ cat file
{
   directiveX
   ...
}
{ 
  directive1
  directive2
  ...
}
{
...
  directive3
}
...
```

This adds `MyDirective` where needed:

```
$ awk -v RS='\n}\n' '{print $0} /{/ {if (!/directiveX/) print "  MyDirective"; print "}"}' file
{
   directiveX
   ...
}
{ 
  directive1
  directive2
  ...
  MyDirective
}
{
...
  directive3
  MyDirective
}
...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It works for the most part, except it adds superfluous directive and closing delimiter at the very end of the file, so now I have a closing delimiter without a matching open. The other thing I limitation I see is that you don't scan for the opening delimiter, your code only looks for a closing one. Is there any way you can improve upon this?

Comment: @MichaelMartinez OK.  I updated it to test for the opening brace which should eliminate both problems.